# Trying use pytest to test CRUD operations and sqlite db but running into 404 error

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

I am testing my CRUD operations with pytest framework. I believe the connection to my test.db file is correct. When running pytest, I get an error that I shouldn't use helper fixture directly. When I remove:

```
json_info = helper(response.response)
```

I receive a 404 error. I use print statements and assert response.headers['Content-Type'] and instead of the expected the response of application/json, I get application/problem+json.

```
import json
import connexion
import pytest
import os

from config import my_app
from db_config import db 

flask_app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__)
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(my_app.root_path, 'database/test.db')
flask_app.app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
flask_app.app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db.init_app(flask_app.app)  
flask_app.add_api('../swagger.yml')


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client():
    with flask_app.app.test_client() as c:
        yield c


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def helper(json_info):
    for info in json_info:
        first_row = info.decode("utf-8")
        return str(json.loads(first_row))


def test_0001_get(client):
    td_username = 'thor'

    response = client.get(f'/users/v1/{td_username}')
    json_info = helper(response.response)

    assert response.status_code == 200
    
    if td_username not in json_info:
        return False
```

Response is expected to be a 200 but getting 404 instead. I do have the data in the test.db.

I believe the reason behind it is because the response isn't coming back in json format this is where the helper fixture will be used. However, I can't call the fixture directly. Is there another way to write this so that the data comes back as json?

Comment: You're not using `helper` as a fixture, so you could simply remove the fixture decorator and use it like a plain old function. However, this is very likely not the reason for the 404.